# Calculate fontSize based on rectangle width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, shapes

I have this method

```
    private Shape CreateTextShape(string text, double placeX, double placeY, double fontSize, System.Windows.Media.Color color, FontFamily fontFamily = null)
    {
        Shape textShape;

        if(fontFamily == null)
            fontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Arial");

        double fontHeight = Math.Ceiling(fontSize * fontFamily.LineSpacing);

        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, new FontStretch());

        FormattedText fText = new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, fontSize, Brushes.Black, 1.25);

        Point textPosition1;
        textPosition1 = new Point(placeX, placeY - fontHeight);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.Data = fText.BuildGeometry(textPosition1);
        path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        textShape = path;
        return textShape;
    }
```

I want it to take account of preferred width and set the fontSize to a value that makes the text as wide as the preferred width:

[image: Current result]

Wanted result:

[image: Wanted result]

Edit:

This code works in a new WPF application. It will create a rectangle with a random size. I want the text to match the same width as the rectangle.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static Random random = new Random();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        double size = random.Next(500);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
        {
            Width = size,
            Height = size,
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 2
        };
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, random.Next(500));
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, random.Next(500));

        canvas.Children.Add(rect);
        canvas.Children.Add(CreateTextShape("Hello world!", Canvas.GetLeft(rect), Canvas.GetTop(rect), 28, Colors.Red, rect.Width)); // Unknown text, should be dynamic
    }

    private Shape CreateTextShape(string text, double placeX, double placeY, double fontSize, System.Windows.Media.Color color, double width)
    {
        // do something with width to adjust the fontsize

        Shape textShape;

        var fontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Arial");

        double fontHeight = Math.Ceiling(fontSize * fontFamily.LineSpacing);

        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, new FontStretch());

        FormattedText fText = new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, fontSize, Brushes.Black, 1.25);

        Point textPosition1;
        textPosition1 = new Point(placeX, placeY - fontHeight);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.Data = fText.BuildGeometry(textPosition1);
        path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        textShape = path;
        return textShape;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1000">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" MaxWidth="1000" MaxHeight="1000"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Edit 2:

The text and size of the rectangle is unknown, this method needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better understanding of your question?

Comment: @Cfun Thanks, it's added in the post now.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set the Transform property of the text Shape to an appropriate ScaleTransform? And why do you have that Shape at all, when you could as well have a simple TextBlock and scale it by its Layout- or RenderTransform?

Comment: I'm not working in a WPF application, this is just an example. I'm drawing overlay on top of camera image frames using the SDK for the VMS [Milestone XProtect](https://www.milestonesys.com). I'll try the ScaleTransform, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, I manged to figure it out with ScaleTransform.

Answer (score 0):

This result works the way I wanted.

```
    private Shape CreateTextShape(string text, double placeX, double placeY, System.Windows.Media.Color color, double width)
    {
        Shape textShape;

        double fontSize = 8;
        FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");

        double fontHeight = Math.Ceiling(fontSize * fontFamily.LineSpacing);

        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, new FontStretch());

        FormattedText fText = new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, fontSize, Brushes.Black, 1.25);
        double scale = width / (fText.Width);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.Data = fText.BuildGeometry(new Point());
        ScaleTransform transform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
        path.Data.Transform = transform;
        Canvas.SetLeft(path, placeX);
        Canvas.SetTop(path, placeY - fontHeight * scale);
        path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        textShape = path;
        return textShape;
    }
```

Comment: Rather than hard coding the pixels per dip value (1.25) you should use `VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(control).PixelsPerDip;`